# Merge 2 branches into new one locally

Tags: git, merge, branch

I know basic merging. To merge `A` into `B`:
`git checkout B`, `git merge A`. But how can I merge into a new branch?

I want a totally new branch where I can work with the result of both `A` and `B`.

In other words, I want my branch `B` as the base in the new branch `C` and get merged by `A`.

So, the result would be `C = B + A`. Not `C = A + B`.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: I'm not sure how `C = A + B` would be different from `C = B + A` for your purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You can do following

1. `git checkout -b "C"` (while being in branch B, then you will have everything from B into C)
2. git merge "A" (while being in branch C, then you have merged all changes from A into new branch C)

Answer (score 0):

You can start by checking out Branch A and then merge its changes into a new branch C, you can follow these steps:

1. **Checkout Branch A:**
   Start by checking out Branch A:

   ```
   git checkout A
   ```
2. **Create and Checkout Branch C:**
   Create a new branch C based on the current state of Branch A and check it out:

   ```
   git checkout -b C
   ```
3. **Merge Branch B into Branch C:**
   Now, you will merge the changes from Branch B into the newly created branch C:

   ```
   git merge B
   ```
4. **Resolve Conflicts (if any):**
   If there are conflicts during the merge, resolve them as usual by editing the conflicted files, adding them with `git add`, and then continuing the merge with `git merge --continue`.
5. **Commit Merged Changes:**
   After resolving conflicts, commit the merged changes:

   ```
   git commit -m "Merged changes from Branch B into C"
   ```
6. **Push the New Branch:**
   If you want to push the new branch to a remote repository:

   ```
   git push origin C
   ```

This approach involves checking out the branch from which you want to start merging (Branch A), creating a new branch (C) based on it, and then merging the changes from the other branch (Branch B) into the new branch (C). This way, you have a clearer starting point for your new branch's history.