# Branching two yet to be accepted PRs

Tags: git

I have two PRs: A and B.

Now, I want to create and start working on a new branch C, for a new PR. But this new branch needs to be "based" over both, A and B. If it is not, it will generate hundreds of conflicts (every commit in A and B will generate a conflict).

After A and B get accepted, I would like branch C to behave as if it was based on the updated "remote master", so I can submit a new PR for C.

In practice, I simply do not want to wait for A and B to get accepted before I can start working on C.

Here is an explanation of the concrete case:

- https://github.com/FreeCAD/FreeCAD/pull/11053#issuecomment-1774063543

Those are the two PRs:

- https://github.com/FreeCAD/FreeCAD/pull/11139
- https://github.com/FreeCAD/FreeCAD/pull/11141

What is the best way to proceed?

I am insecure about the correct way to proceed in this situation. It is not that I do not know how to branch from A and then merge from B. It is just that I do not know what is the correct way to proceed.

Git is a very versatile tool that can be used in the wrong way or in the correct way. The internet is full of people giving wrong advice all over. I thought this would be a very legitimate question.

Then I thought SO would be the place to ask! It seems I was wrong... here, I am always treated as if my questions are dumb. I am giving up on SO. It is a great place to look for answers... but not a great place to ask for help. I need a place where people are dumb in the same level I am... not a place full of geniuses...

Comment: Simply start working on C based on A and B and rebase it onto master once A and B have been merged.

Comment: @mkrieger1: Branch C is not created yet. I need it to be created and I need it to contain A and B. The merge cannot come after the changes in C, because they will conflict. I do not know how to "base on A and B". :-)

Comment: So create C based on B and merge A into C (or vice versa, i.e. create C based on A and merge B into C).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge 2 branches into new one locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73357575/merge-2-branches-into-new-one-locally)

Comment: @mkrieger1: I will do the way you propose. And if you do not post it as an answer, I will... after C gets merged and I am sure it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `C` branch starting from `A` and merge `B`.... Let's call this merge commit `X`... Start working on `C` stuff there.... When both branches are merged into `main`, rebase `C` like this to clean up the previous local starting point you created from `A` and `B`:

```
git rebase X C --onto origin/main
```